# mplayer output 4 audio channels to jack

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mplayer, jack

I am struggling with getting mplayer to reproduce a 4 audio channel wav file.

I created a 4chn audio file.
Want mplayer to player, and output it to jack.
The problem is that i am only able to get in jack 2 mplayer channels.

if I do:

```
mplayer -ao jack -channels 4 test_4chan_2.wav
```

mplayer plays and responds:

```
laying test_4chan_2.wav.
libavformat version 54.6.100 (internal)
Audio only file format detected.
Load subtitles in ./
==========================================================================
Opening audio decoder: [pcm] Uncompressed PCM audio decoder
AUDIO: 44100 Hz, 4 ch, s16le, 2822.4 kbit/100.00% (ratio: 352800->352800)
Selected audio codec: [pcm] afm: pcm (Uncompressed PCM)
==========================================================================
AO: [jack] 44100Hz 2ch floatle (4 bytes per sample)
Video: no video
Starting playback...
```

and jack has only the following outputs:

```
system:capture_1
system:capture_2
system:playback_1
system:playback_2
MPlayer [14434]:out_0
MPlayer [14434]:out_1
```

So it seems that mplayer recognizes that the input file as 4ch
but on AO: [jack] only 2ch appear

if I try the same with ecasound:

```
ecasound -f 16,4,44100 -i test_4chan_2.wav -o jack
```

in Jack ecasoud appears with 4 outputs

```
system:capture_1
system:capture_2
system:playback_1
system:playback_2
ecasound:out_1
ecasound:out_2
ecasound:out_3
ecasound:out_4
```

Do you have any idea of what could I be doing wrong??
I am running Debian (Jessy) and mplayer 1.1-4.7

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Solved. Only need to upgrade mplayer to 4.8, in Debian Sid. 
And

```
mplayer -channels 4 -ao jack:noconnect 4chn_file.wav
```

did the trick.
The -ao jack:noconnect means: 
-ao audio-output: jack 
noconnect: prevent mplayer to make 1-to-1 connections. As I have 2 different stereo audio sound cards, mplayer was only giving me 2 channels. And this option disables that *start* behavior.

hope it will be of help to someone else ,)